# Problems with Laravel data validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I'm having some problems with validations in my api.

I need to send a json array like this:

```
[
    {
        "acktime": "2021-09-25 08:45:07",
        "temp": 15.6
    },
    {
        "acktime": "2021-09-25 08:45:07",
        "temp": 15.6
    }
probably more array....
]
```

I would like to vaidate one by one array and store only the valid data returning error for unvalid data, I have tried a foreach cylce but it convert the array to object but the validate::make want only array.

I have tried this:

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        '*.acktime' => 'required',
        '*.temp' => 'required|numeric'
        ]);

    $validatedData = $validator->validated();
    var_dump($validatedData);
    return response()->json($validatedData);
```

But If I send wrong data I get only error without having valid data, so I've tried this way:

```
foreach($datas as $data){
    $arr = (array)$data;
    $validator = Validator::make($arr, [
        'acktime' => 'required',
        'temp' => 'required|numeric'
        ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        continue;
    } else {
        $newrawData = new rawData([
            'acktime' => $data->acktime,
            'temp' => $data->temp,
            'synctime' => now()
        ]);
        $newrawData->save();
        }
    }
    return response('OK', 200); //or error if some data are not ok
}
```

In this way it work, bot I have no idea about get, a probable, validation error..(for the moment there's a continue for continue the cycle) any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for approaching this kind of validation:

1. make a custom rule in laravel validation from below and put your validation code in it and this will work:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

2. easier way:

   ```
   $data = [ 'data' => $requests->all() ]; 

   $validator = Validator::make($data, [
       'data.*.name' => 'required|string',
       'data.*.' => 'required|string'
    ]);
   ```

Comment: I think the first is the most correct one, but I don't  know ho collect errors, I tried to create an $err array but using $err.push(£errorcomingfromvalidator) function cause error